# Clojure how to format this shell command

Tags: shell, clojure

First off I understand there are sftp wrapper for Clojure and I am using one however; this is a very specific use case which can't use such wrapper.

I want to execute the following command from Clojure (tested manually the command works in the terminal)

```
sshpass -p <password> sftp <user>@<host> <<< $'cd <dir>\n put <file>\n bye'
```

with anything is `<>` swapped with real data.

I am using the `clojure.java.shell` wrapper and have tried the following:

```
(shell/sh "sshpass" (str " -p " password) "sftp" (str username "@" host "<<< $\'cd" path "\nput" file "\nbye\'")))
```

But it doesn't work. I assume my syntax is incorrect but im using a ns reloaded so the error isnt throw the namespace just constantly reloads which is a pain.

I need to avoid using a batch file, I need to inline the command, but as I said if I run the command manually it works.

Is my syntax incorrect?

update:

In the repl this is returned:

```
{:exit 0, :out "", :err "Connected to <host>.\n"}
```

Comment: "-p" is one argument and then the password is another argument. Don't `(str ..)` them.

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't have to escape **'** character. moreover, it shows the following exception in repl:
   *RuntimeException Unsupported escape character: \'  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)
   RuntimeException EOF while reading string  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)*
2. str doesn't automatically add spaces between arguments

   (str "username" "@" "host" "<<< $cd" "path" "\nput" "file" "\nbye'")

produces the string *"username@host<<< $cdpath\nputfile\nbye'"*

Hope fixing these ones could help